# In clojure, how to write a defn-like macro where the function will exit on first failure?

Tags: macros, clojure

In clojure, I would like to write a `defn-my` macro that creates a function with a `body`. And when this function is executed, it exits on first statement that doesn't return 0.

For example:

```
(defn f1[] (println "f1") 5)
(defn f2[] (println "f2") 0)
(defn-my foo[] (f1) (f2))     
(defn-my bar[] (f2) (f1))
(foo); should execute f1 and exit
(bar); should execute f2 and then f1
```

Comment: The expressions in your defn-my examples never return null; they are vars, not tuples.  Is that really what you meant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are asking for something like this:

```
(defmacro and-zero
  ([] true)
  ([x] (zero? x))
  ([x & next] 
    `(let [and# (zero? ~x)]
       (if and# 
         (and-not-zero ~@next)
         and#))))

user=> (and-zero 0 0 0)
true
user=> (and-zero 0 1 0)
false
```

The macro assumes every expression evaluates to a number.  It will throw an exception if, for example, an expression evaluates to `nil`.

Then you can write yout `defn-my` like this:

```
(defmacro defn-my [ & body ] `(and-zero ~@body))
```

Comment: Thx! You got me right. Could you please edit the question to make it clearer?

Comment: Could you tell me what to do if I want to apply a predicate to `~@body`? For example `#(= 0 %)` to stop when the return value is not zero. Thx

Comment: I liked the `(and @body)`. But in my case the function should exit on first statement that doesn't return 0. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Just leverage the short-circuit behaviour of `and`:

```
(defn foo []
  (and (f1) (f2)))

(defn bar []
  (and (f2) (f1)))
```

Results:

```
user=> (foo)
f1
nil
user=> (bar)
f2
f1
nil
```

You can get the opposite behaviour, terminating on first non-nil, with `or`.

Comment: Please update your answer. I modified the question a little bit. Thx

Comment: Also, I seek for a solution where I don't have to modify the code of on `bar` and `foo`.

Comment: You post a lot of odd questions.  Perhaps you should spend time learning how to think in *clojure*, rather than simply trying to bend it to how *you* think something should be solved.  Related to this, almost everything you've posted smells strongly like an XY Problem: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: My real issue  is that I want a macro like `deftest` but if one of the expectations inside a test fails, I want the test to abort immediately. Can you think of a better way to formulatemy question?

Comment: Make a new question and this time, instead of asking how to implement your solution, just state the actual problem you have, and the actual code you're using.  XY Problems waste everyone's time.

Comment: To me it seems exactly the same. In this case, I don't think there is a XY problem. If you think so, please explain why.

Comment: @Yahonathan I would formulate the question like this: "How do I write a macro like deftest but if one of the expectations inside a test fails, the entire test fails immediately?"

Comment: I have a similar (but not identical) need, and so I posted a question on the SQA site: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2705/open-source-clojure-test-framework-that-skips-rest-of-test-on-assertion-failure